# Display the Cent currency symbol?

Tags: android, text, currency

How do you display `9&cent` as `9¢` in Android programatically?

Comment: In your code, or just in general use of the phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Spanned spannded = Html.fromHtml("&cent;");
        String cent = spannded.toString();
```

**Declare the string cent in strings.xml fi you still getting issue with that**

Comment: It is probably accepted but I think it should have a trailing semicolon to be correct.

Comment: No jennifer its a community NO THANKS NO SORRY have a nice CENT DAY

Answer (score 2):

In your strings.xml file you can use any Unicode sign you want.

For example, the Unicode number for cent sign is 00A2:

```
<string name="cent_sign">&#x00A2;</string>
```

You can see a comprehensive list of Unicode signs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)